# NullPointerException error for a String variable using webDriver.getWindowHandle

Tags: java, selenium, junit, nullpointerexception

I am getting NullPointerException in my JUnit test when I try to get the current webdriver Window Handle and pass it to a String variable and I don't understand why?

```
@Test

public void citationLinkerTest() {

//BeforeClass creates and instance of the browser and goes to the target URL.


//ERROR AT THIS LINE: 

String firstWindowHandle = webDriver.getWindowHandle();


assertEquals("Expecting only one window", 1, webDriver.getWindowHandles().size());

}
```

************  ERROR:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.sersol.alejp.tests.EJournalPortalNewUIIT.citationLinkerTest(EJournalPortalNewUIIT.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatcher$1.evaluate(TestWatcher.java:55)
    at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:27)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:78)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:212)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
```

Comment: how / where did you define and  initialize `webDriver`?

Comment: your best bet..run your code in debug mode..or in debug mode set debug point on NPE exception to see which part of code gives u NPE

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, but because of my less reputation points i could not put this answer in reply, but as a new response.

As @Kiril S mentioned in the comments, the problem could be how and where you defined the WebDriver. You did not give the code of that part, so assuming the problem is there. If you are using multiple annotations you have to mention the driver at the class level so that it can be accessed across the class and all methods.

Comment: Thank you all for you feedback. You were all correct. I ended up moving the code (line that was causing error) in a different class file where I was initializing everything correctly and my test proceeded without error.

Answer (score 0):

your test seems not initialized the webDriver so getWindowHandle() returns the null causes this issue